# What are Euler density and Weyl invariants?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, conformal-geometry

- I would like to know as to what is the definition and significance of what are called "Euler density" and "Weyl invariants" (of weight $-d$ on a $d-$manifold)
- Do many (which?) of them vanish when integrated on a compact $d$-manifold? (at least $S^d$?)
- And for the case of $d=2$ do all of these just collapse into one quantity the scalar curvature?

---

One might want to look at this (partially answered) [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139685/proof-of-the-general-expression-for-anomaly-in-a-cft-and-its-partition-function/140701#140701) of mine to see my motivations.

Answer (score 1):

The Euler density is defined as $\mathcal{R}^n$ in these equations

[image]

[image]

Its integral over a manifold is the Euler characteristic up to a constant.
That is its main significance.
It also means that the integral is a topological invariant and vanishes when the Euler characteristic is zero.

In 2-d the Euler characteristic is the Ricci scalar.

This [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6793/22278) and a section of this blog post [blog post](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/07/euler-characteristic.html) have more information on the Euler density.